# How to save event data into an xml file from dhtmlxscheduler

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I need to save event data to an xml file.I need to do this using a java code.i am using html5.
So from the javascript i need to call this java code and need to save event text,date and other details to an xml file.And whenever the data is needed it should be displayed back in the dhtmlx scheduler.How can i do this?

```
function init() {

    scheduler.config.xml_date="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";

    scheduler.config.prevent_cache = true;



    scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2010,0,20),"month");

    scheduler.load("data/data.xml");

}



function show() {

    alert(scheduler.toXML());

}

function save() {

    var form = document.forms[0];

    form.action = "./data/xml_writer.php";

    form.elements.data.value = scheduler.toXML();

    form.submit();

}

function download() {

    var form = document.forms[0];

    form.action = "./data/xml_download.php";

    form.elements.data.value = scheduler.toXML();

    form.submit();

}
```

**xml_writer.php**

```
  <?php

 file_put_contents("./data.xml",$_POST["data"]);

 header("Location:./dummy.html");

 ?>

<?php

if(empty($_POST['data'])) {

echo "why";

exit;
```

}

**xml_download**

```
 $filename = "data.xml";



 header("Cache-Control: ");

 header("Content-type: text/plain");

 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');



 echo $_POST['data'];



 ?>
```

**html code**

```
<form action="./php/xml_writer.php" method="post" target="hidden_frame" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="" id="data">

</form>

<iframe src='about:blank' frameborder="0" style="width:0px; height:0px;" id="hidden_frame" name="hidden_frame"></iframe>

<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>

    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">

        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>

        <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>

        <input type="button" name="download" value="Download" onclick="download()" style="right:500px;" />

        <input type="button" name="show" value="Show" onclick="show()" style="right:400px;" />

        <input type="button" name="save" value="Save" onclick="save()" style="right:300px;" />

        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>

        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>

        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="dhx_cal_header">

    </div>

    <div class="dhx_cal_data">

    </div>
```

This much code i have.But code for saving to an xml file is in php.I need java code instead of php.

Comment: if you post your code and where you are struck, we can help

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are using HTML5 can you show us this code. Why `XML` and why `Java` particularly as it's hard to tell what your use case is.